# Run installed application on iPad (device) from Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, ipad, terminal

1. I build the application for iPad (from a Terminal) using:

   > xcodebuild ARCHS=armv7 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO VALID_ARCHS=armv7 -scheme MyApp -sdk iphoneos build
2. Then I deploy it to my iPad using fruitstrap:

   > ./fruitstrap -b Mobile/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/
3. At the next step I have a problem: I need to run the installed application from a Terminal to be able to run the nightly-iterations on Hudson CI.

Any ideas on how to do it?